# How can i import only two tables into hive using sqoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop

I seen in **sqoop** to import table we have import-all-tables or simply import table name into **hive** but i have 100s of tables and i want to import only two tables at one time,
How can i acheive this?

Comment: use a shell script which will pick from list of 100s and then using loop it will run them 2 at a time.

Answer (score 2):

you can do a  shell script like this :

```
while read line;
do

    DBNAME=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1` 
    tableName=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f2`


    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$QUEUE_NAME --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --table $tableName  --target-dir $DATA_COLLECTOR/$tableName  --fields-terminated-by '\001'  -m 1 

done<inputFile
```